# Symmetry of certain improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Let $a < b < c < d$ be real numbers. Is it true that the following identity holds?  $$\int_a^b \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{|x-a||x-b||x-c||x-d|}}= \int_c^d \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{|x-a||x-b||x-c||x-d|}}$$

A friend of mine told me a friend of his said that it was true. But alas, we don't have a clue of how to attack this. We made a couple of cases in Mathematica and it seems to be true, unless we missed something simple.

Comment: That identity implies that $b - a = d - c$. Is it under those assumptions?

Comment: Also, unless $a$ or $b$ or $c$ or $d$ are $\pm\infty$, this is NOT an Improper Integral, it's a **Definite Integral**.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. All four numbers are singularities of the integrand, and they are fixed a priori. The integral is improper.

Comment: Would've been more interesting if you made: $\int_a^b \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{|x-a||x-b|}}= \int_c^d \frac{{\rm d}x}{\sqrt{|x-c||x-d|}}$, where $b - a = d - c$ is not necessarily true and $a<b<c<d$

Answer (score 3):

> There're similar results as in *Giovanni Mingari Scarpello, Daniele Ritelli*, [**The hyperelliptic integrals and π**](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X09001796), Journal of Number Theory 129 (2009) 3094–3108.

\begin{align}
  \int_{d}^{c} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a-x)(b-x)(c-x)(x-d)}} &=
  \frac{2}{\sqrt{(a-c)(b-d)}}
  K\left( \sqrt{\frac{(a-b)(c-d)}{(a-c)(b-d)}}\, \right) \\
  \int_{b}^{a} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a-x)(b-x)(c-x)(x-d)}} &=
  \frac{2}{\sqrt{(a-c)(b-d)}}
  K\left( \sqrt{\frac{(a-b)(c-d)}{(a-c)(b-d)}}\, \right) \\ \\
\end{align}

with convention $a>b>c>d$.  These can also be verified by *Alan Jeffrey,‎ Daniel Zwillinger*, **Table of Integrals, Series, and Products**.  Also,

$$  \int_{c}^{b} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a-x)(b-x)(x-c)(x-d)}} =
  \frac{2}{\sqrt{(a-c)(b-d)}}
  K\left( \sqrt{\frac{(b-c)(a-d)}{(a-c)(b-d)}}\, \right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

A low level verification.

From the fact that the [cross-ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio#Definition) $(a,b;c,d)$ and $(c,d;a,b)$ are equal, it follows that the homography $f(t)=\frac{pt+q}{rt+s}$ that maps $a$ to $c$, $b$ to $d$ and $c$ to $a$, will also map $d$ to $b$. Solving for the coefficients gives $$p=bd-ac,\; q=abc-abd+acd-bcd,\; r=d-c+b-a,\;s=-p$$
The resulting $f(t)$ is its own inverse and has domain and range $\Bbb R \setminus \{t_0\}$, where $t_0=-\frac sr$.

Now $t_0-b=\frac{(b-a)(c-b)}{d-c+b-a}>0$, so $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and maps that interval to $[c,d]$ (and back).

Transforming the first integral in the question by applying the parameter change $x=f(y)$ has the second integral as result because $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{ps-rq}{(ry+s)^2}\qquad \mathrm {with}\qquad ps-rq=(b-a)(d-c)(c-b)(d-a)$$
$$f(y)-a=\frac{(b-a)(d-a)(y-c)}{ry+s}$$
$$f(y)-b=\frac{(b-a)(c-b)(y-d)}{ry+s}$$
$$f(y)-c=-\frac{(c-b)(d-c)(y-a)}{ry+s}$$
$$f(y)-d=-\frac{(d-a)(d-c)(y-b)}{ry+s}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $a<b<c<d$, we have two cases:

**1)** If $a<x<b$, then 
$$|x-a||x-b||x-c||x-d| = (x-a)(b-x)(c-x)(d-x) = (a-x)(b-x)(c-x)(x-d).$$

**2)** If $c<x<d$, then
$$|x-a||x-b||x-c||x-d| = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(d-x) = (a-x)(b-x)(c-x)(x-d).$$

Therefore,

$$\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-a||x-b||x-c||x-d|}} \ dx = \int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{(a-x)(b-x)(c-x)(x-d)}} \ dx$$

and

$$\int_c^d \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-a||x-b||x-c||x-d|}} \ dx = \int_c^d \frac{1}{\sqrt{(a-x)(b-x)(c-x)(x-d)}} \ dx.$$

Now use the answer given by @Ng Chung Tak to conclude these two integrals are equal.