# Closed form of $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a) (x-b) (x-c) (x-d) (x-e)}} \, \rm{d}x$

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

I want to find the closed form of this integral:

$$
I_5=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a) (x-b) (x-c) (x-d) (x-e)}} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

where $a<b<c<d<e$.

---

##### My attempt

My idea is to find a transformation so that the part in the root sign can be reduced.

I solved the three and four cases with this idea.

For

$$
I_3=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a) (x-b) (x-c)}} \, \rm{d}x
$$

let

$$t^2 = \dfrac{b - a}{x - a}$$

then

$$
\begin{aligned}
x&=\frac{a t^2-a+b}{t^2}\\
\rm{d}x&=\frac{2 (a-b)}{t^3}\,\rm{d}t
\end{aligned}
$$

and then

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_3
&=\int\frac{-2\,\rm{d}t}{\sqrt{(1-t^2) \left(b-a-(c-a) t^2\right)}}\\
&=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{b-a}}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-t^2\right) \left(1-\dfrac{c-a}{b-a} t^2\right)}}\,\rm{d}t\\
&=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{b-a}}F\left(\arcsin t,\frac{c-a}{b-a}\right)\\
&=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{b-a}}F\left(\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a-x}},\frac{a-c}{a-b}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

So for

$$
I_4=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a) (x-b) (x-c)(x-d)}} \, \rm{d}x
$$

the same let

$$
\begin{aligned}
t^2&=\frac{(b-d)(x-a)}{(a-d) (x-b)}\\
x &= \frac{b t^2 (d-a)+a (b-d)}{t^2 (d-a)+b-d}\\
\rm{d}x&=\frac{2 t (a-b) (a-d) (b-d)}{\left(t^2 (d-a)+b-d\right)^2}\, \rm{d}t
\end{aligned}
$$

then

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_4
&=\int\frac{-2\,\rm{d}t}{\sqrt{\left(1-t^2\right) \left((a-c) (b-d)- (a-d) (b-c)t^2\right)}}\\
&=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{(a-c) (b-d)}}F\left(\arcsin t,\frac{(a-d) (b-c)}{(a-c) (b-d)}\right)\\
&=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{(a-c) (b-d)}}F\left(\arcsin\left(\sqrt{\frac{(b-d) (x-a)}{(a-d) (x-b)}}\right),\frac{(a-d) (b-c)}{(a-c) (b-d)}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

I have not found such a transformation for $I_5$ yet.

I tried the undetermined coefficient method

let

$$t^2=\frac{m x+n}{u x+v}$$

then this expanded part needs to be a polynomial with respect to $t^2$

$$P_5=\frac{2 t \sqrt{m-t^2 u} (m v-n u)}{\sqrt{-\left(\left(a \left(m-t^2 u\right)+n+t^2 (-v)\right) \left(b \left(m-t^2 u\right)+n+t^2 (-v)\right) \left(c \left(m-t^2 u\right)+n+t^2 (-v)\right) \left(d \left(m-t^2 u\right)+n+t^2 (-v)\right) \left(e \left(m-t^2 u\right)+n+t^2 (-v)\right)\right)}}$$

Can't solve suitable $(m,n,u,v)$

Comment: The first one is an elliptic integral ("Carlson integral") : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%28%28x-a%29%28x-b%29%28x-c%29%29

Comment: @JeanMarie, For $a<b<c$, should be $$\int \frac{\rm{d}x}{\sqrt{(x-a) (x-b) (x-c)}}=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{b-a}}F\left(\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{a-b}{a-x}},\frac{a-c}{a-b}\right)$$

Comment: Well, nice keyword Carlson integral  RF. I didn't know this before, I'll take a look at the reference.

Comment: A reference for the second integral : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2591606/305862 (found using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/ But I doubt that the third integral with a fifth degree polynomial has a tractable expression.

Comment: Do you know the Bring-Jerrard form of the quintic (fifth degree polynomial) ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical

Comment: $$I_4=\frac{2}{\sqrt{(d-a) (c-b)}}\,\,F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{ (x-b)(d-a)}{(x-a) (d-b)}}\right)|\frac{(c-a)   (d-b)}{(d-a) (c-b)}\right)$$

Comment: In general, $I_5$ os not an elliptic integral.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral  A more general class: the abelian integrals.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_integral

Comment: @GEdgar. Abelian integrals are also named hyperelliptic integrals

Comment: An example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3941748/305862) solved with a series expansion.